# I want to write a function in JAVA to compare list of Maps where it should print the result if any difference is there not only boolean value

Tags: java

Consider below List of Map:

```
List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> allTableData = new ArrayList<>();

    
LinkedHashMap<String, String> eachRowData = new LinkedHashMap<>();
eachRowData.put("key1", "value1");
eachRowData.put("key2", "value2");
allTableData.add(eachRowData);
System.out.println(allTableData);

    
List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> allTableData1 = new ArrayList<>();

    
LinkedHashMap<String, String> eachRowData1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
eachRowData1.put("key1", "value4");
eachRowData1.put("key2", "value2");
allTableData1.add(eachRowData1);
```

In case of difference it should print/return like allTableData key1=value1 and allTableData1 key1=value4 with index where value is mismatched.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear. Your second code snippet simply mimics the first. And I don’t know what the title means exactly.

Comment: Why not define a class ([record*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395)) to represent your rows? Your approach seems like a convoluted way to represent tabular data.

Comment: Second snippet represents 2nd List of Map to be compare against List of Map1.
If you see in second snippet key1=value4 and in first key1=value1 so here value is different this I want to print like value for key1 is different in List of Map1 and list of Map2 also k/v from both list of maps.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The data structure is not conducive to what you want.

Thus, *first* convert it into something that can get the job done. THEN, you can do it.

The data structure you want maps a given key into *all* unique values. Then later you can print all keys for which the list of observed values is larger than 1.

```
HashMap<String, Set<String>> allValues = new HashMap<>();
for (var inMap : allTableData) {
    for (var e : inMap.entrySet()) {
        allValues
          .computeIfAbsent(e.getKey(), k -> new HashSet<>())
          .add(e.getValue());
    }
}

for (var e : allValues.entrySet()) {
    if (e.getValue().size() < 2) continue;
    System.out.printf("Key %s has values: %s\n", e.getKey(), e.getValue());
}
```